# Prove, that $tB$ is a borel set if and only if $B$ is a borel set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $t > 0$ and $B \subset \mathbb R^{d}.$ And $tB = \{tb : b\in B\}.$

Prove, that $tB$ is a borel set if and only if $B$ is a borel set.

Any hints would be great. Moreover, how do we in general show that, some set is a borel set?

Comment: Hint: Consider the function $f(x) = tx$.  This is continuous.  Does this tell you anything about what $f(B) = tB$ looks like?  You could alternatively set this up as $f'(x) = \frac{x}{t}$ and consider what the inverse image of $B$ looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: any homeomorphism preserves the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets.

Comment: Could you tell me how we prove this fact? It is surely useful, but I need some evidence to convince myself :)

Comment: @janusz: A homeomorphism is open and preserves arbitrary (in particular, countable) unions and intersections (and the same is true about its inverse).